# Finding the basis vectors used to describe a vector, given its components

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, change-of-basis

I have a vector:
$$\mathbf{v} = v_x \hat{x} + v_y \hat{y} + v_z \hat{z}$$

Which I know the components for ($ v_x , v_y, v_z$) for in the normal basis.

I also have the components of the vector in a new basis:

$$\mathbf{v} = v_1 \hat{e_1} + v_2 \hat{e_2} + v_3 \hat{e_3}$$

In this new basis, I know the components ($ v_1 , v_2, v_3$), but I do not know the basis vectors ($\hat{e_1},\hat{e_2},\hat{e_3}$).

I need to find the basis ($\hat{e_1},\hat{e_2},\hat{e_3}$) in terms of the normal basis - so this means finding the components:

\begin{bmatrix}
    \hat{e_1}\cdot \hat x      & \hat{e_1}\cdot \hat y  & \hat{e_1}\cdot \hat z \\
    \hat{e_2}\cdot \hat x      & \hat{e_2}\cdot \hat y  & \hat{e_2}\cdot \hat z \\
    \hat{e_3}\cdot \hat x      & \hat{e_3}\cdot \hat y  & \hat{e_3}\cdot \hat z
\end{bmatrix}

However, I believe for the components I have specified there is many (perhaps an infinite number) of possible bases. So I have an additional constraint:

$$\hat{e_2}\cdot \mathbf{w} = 0 $$

Where $w$ is another vector which I know in the standard basis. i.e. I know the components ($w_x,w_y,w_z$).

I also have the constraint that the basis ($\hat{e_1},\hat{e_2},\hat{e_3}$) is orthogonal - i.e. $\hat{e_i}\cdot\hat{e_j} = \delta_{i,j}$.

So I need to know how to find the set of possible ($\hat{e_1},\hat{e_2},\hat{e_3}$) basis vectors, and from this set, how to apply these constraints to deduce the correct basis.

Please help!

Comment: Are you talking only about orthonormal bases? Otherwise you still have many possible choices: as an example take $v=(1,0,0)$ and $w=(0,0,1)$ and $v_1=1,v_2=0,v_3=0$; possible bases include  $(1,0,0), (0,1,0)$ and any $(0,\lambda,1)$.

Comment: Yes all the bases here are orthogonal, so perhaps this is an additional condition which can be used that $e_i\cdot e_j = \delta_{i,j} $

Comment: You'd better edit the question, then and put in all the conditions.